# tufte-book class word wrapping problems

Tags: graphics, line-breaking

I am having problems with text wrapping around a margin figure when I use the tufte-book class. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, bm, graphicx}
\begin{document}
Now is the time
\begin{marginfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{file}
    \caption{Moving Charge}
\end{marginfigure}
for all good old folks to party!
\end{document}
```

The pdf output is attached.

Any ideas? Thanks.

[image: .pdf output]

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you just put the full sentence `Now is the time for all good old folks to party!` before `\begin{marginfigure}`?

Comment: The words are not wrapping because a margin figure cannot wrap words in the main text: margins are "outside" the main text block. Just make some vertical space if you want. But that would look weird if it doesn't serve a purpose.